# Differentiating/integrating a multivariate function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

When we differentiate a multivariate function $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x$, we write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and differentiate by treating $y$ as a constant.

When we integrate $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x$, we write $\int f\ dx$ and integrate it by treating $y$ as a constant.

Is there a reason for why we don't specify $\partial x$ when integrating a multivariate function?